# Retrieving unsigned zerofill int from URL

Tags: php, mysql, url, get

Scenario: I'm passing an ID of an account through the URL. The account ID must always have 5 digits, that;s why I'm using zerofill int and automatically incrementing it every user account that I add in my database. By passing the ID, I'll use it to query other tables involving the user account

Problem: It seems that if I retrieve the ID from the URL through $_GET, it gives me a normal int instead. Is it possible to get the zerofill version of this number to compare it to my database?

Example:
website.php?id=00032

P.S. I am a newbie in PHP so please do go easy on me. Also, I am aware that passing ID's through the URL is a major security issue but I'm not concerned about that right now

Comment: "it gives me a normal int instead" --- how do you know that? `var_dump()`? "I am aware that passing ID's through the URL is a major security issue" --- it's not. Stackoverflow passes question id in the url and they are still here and alive.

Comment: Let me rephrase that. When I retrieve it through get, it returns a string, since when I echo it, it gives me the usual 00032 like the example. When I cast it to INT so that I can actually compare it to the database which is also of INT type, it removes the zeros and leaves me with 32, at least that's what I think is happening

Comment: that's right, because it's `32` integer, not `000000000000000000032`. You asked php to convert a string to an integer - it performed it. Not sure what is the problem then.

Comment: well, that's the exact question right there. Is there any way to make  it a zerofill int?

Comment: nope, integer is a number. You're confusing data with its representation.

Answer (score 1):

You can either cast it to int or check using `is_int`/ `is_integer`/`filter_var`

Also, I personally don't like the idea of using the common **id** for identifying users. You might want to create a function that generates the user account based on the id plus the current date and maybe some random string as well.

Comment: "I personally don't like the idea of using the common id for identifying users" --- could you clarify that?